# Minimum path SUM calculation in a obstacle matrix?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have a matrix with obstacles and several terminals, how do you find the point that has minimum path sum from this point to all the terminals?

Comment: Does every point have a positive value? Or the path sum just means the number of points?

Comment: You can think it as you are going to build up an intermediate station on Mars, where you have multiple base stations(terminals) and obstacles. You want to minimize the total path from the intermediate station to all the base stations. So the path here means probably the distance between 2 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assign 0 to each matrix position
2. For each terminal, *t*

   1. Do a breadth first traversal of the matrix
   2. Each node traversal increment the current matrix position with the current depth (the current length back to *t*)
3. Scan through the matrix for the position with lowest value (sum of distances to each terminal)

Comment: This is really great! The time complexity will be knm, k is the number of terminals, and n, m are the sizes of the matrix. And further more, can we use more efficient algorithm to search in a matrix for the lowest value?

Comment: I don't think the final search for the minimum value matters much compared to the computation done in the previous step. (Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it answers your question.)